The redirection to the main page after login or registration only works after the second form submission (only on Mobile)
In my Group Counter App, I implemented authorization functionality. Earlier, I had a problem with authorization on PC, and I created a question where I solved my problem. However, now that I have finished my app, I noticed that this problem still exists on mobile. I don't encounter any problems with logging in on my PC, but when I try to sign in or sign up from a mobile device (in my case, an iPhone 13), after I log in, I stay on the same page. I need to submit the form a second time to be redirected to the menu page (in my case, "/").
This is my project page on GitHub: click
And this is a live page. You can try to log in from a mobile device and see the issue: click
This  AuthProvider component:
export const AuthAPI = createContext<null | TAuthAPI>(null);

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const setCurrentUserId = useContextSelector(ContextAPI, (v) => v?.setCurrentUserId);

  const { logInValues, SignInInputConstructor, logInError, setLogInError } = useLogIn();
  const { signUpValues, SignUpInputConstructor, signUpError, setSignUpError } = useAuth();
  const { handleLogout, logOutError } = useLogOut();

  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<firebase.User | undefined | null>(undefined);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const logIn = (email: string, password: string) => {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  };
  const signup = (email: string, password: string) => {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  };

  const handleLogIn = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!/^[a-zA-Z\s].*@.*$/.test(logInValues.email)) {
      return setLogInError("Email is not correct");
    }
    if (logInValues.password === "") {
      return setLogInError("password field can not be empty");
    }

    try {
      setLogInError("");
      setLoading?.(true);

      await logIn(logInValues.email, logInValues.password);

      setTimeout(() => navigate("/"));
    } catch (errors) {
      setLogInError("Failed to log-in in account");
    } finally {
      setLoading?.(false);
    }
  };
  const handleRegister = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (signUpValues.password !== signUpValues.passwordConfirm) {
      return setSignUpError("Passwords do not match");
    }
    if (!/^[a-zA-Z\s].*@.*$/.test(signUpValues.email)) {
      return setSignUpError("Email is not correct");
    }
    if (signUpValues.password === "") {
      return setSignUpError("Password field can not be empty");
    } else {
      try {
        setSignUpError("");
        setLoading?.(true);
        await signup(signUpValues.email, signUpValues.password);
        setTimeout(() => navigate("/"));
      } catch (errors) {
        setSignUpError("Failed to create an account");
      }
      setLoading?.(false);
    }
  };

  const vals: TAuthAPI = {
    handleLogout,
    logOutError,
    signUpValues,
    SignUpInputConstructor,
    handleRegister,
    signUpError,
    logInValues,
    SignInInputConstructor,
    handleLogIn,
    logInError,
    currentUser,
    loading,
    setLoading,
    setSignUpError,
    setLogInError,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading?.(false);
      setCurrentUserId?.(user?.uid || null);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
  return <AuthAPI.Provider value={vals}> {!loading && children} </AuthAPI.Provider>;
};
export default AuthProvider;

and this is my main App.tsx component, where i providing my context data:
function App() {
  return (
    <SBox>
      <ContextProvider>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Outlet />
        </AuthProvider>
      </ContextProvider>
    </SBox>
  );
}

and this is my Main component with all routes:
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  [
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <App />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/sign-in",
          element: <LogIn />,
        },
        {
          path: "/sign-up",
          element: <Register />,
        },
        {
          path: "/",
          element: <PrivateRoute />,
          children: [
            {
              path: "/",
              element: <GroupMenu />,
              children: [
                {
                  path: "/add-group",
                  element: <AddGroupModal />,
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              path: "/:groupId",
              element: <GroupContent />,
              children: [
                {
                  path: "/:groupId/:groupItemId",
                  element: <GroupContentModal />,
                },
                {
                  path: "/:groupId/new-field",
                  element: <AddNewFieldModal />,
                },
                {
                  path: "/:groupId/print-content",
                  element: <PrintContent />,
                },
              ],
            },

            {
              path: "/dashboard",
              element: <Dashboard />,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  { basename: "/thatswhy_items_counter/" }
);
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(<Main />);


I've tried to change the useEffect conditions and to use setTimeout for placing the navigate("/") function at the end of all enqueued callbacks.
